# .htaccess redirect url with certain parameters to homepage

Tags: .htaccess, url, parameters, url-rewriting

The parameters are: "route=product/search" and "path=0". I already tried a lot of things but my knowledge of .htaccess is limited.

I want to redirect the following URL:
    www.example.com/index.php?route=product/search&path=0

to
    www.example.com

Whatever I try, it doesn't seem to work. What's the best solution for this?

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### below send all calls to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)route=product/search(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)path=0(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add those directives to your  main `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)route=product/search(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)path=0(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /? [R=301,NC]
```

you have also a RewriteCond missing in the fourth RewriteRule (which prevent url that starts with index.php from the rewrite), your .htaccess would be:

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### below send all calls to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)route=product/search(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)path=0(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /? [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Dear Amine, thanks for the answer. Sadly, it's not working. I updated the question with my htaccess file.

Comment: I've forgot to append a backslash to the rwriterule which will prevent query string from being appended, I've updated your .htaccess, give it a try(remember to clear your browser cache before testing)